# Force HTTP on backend only Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WP Multisite install with 5 subsites.
I am having issues on the backend of the subsites. Acymailing doesn't behave correctly if running in https, but it's OK with http.

I need to disable https on all backends, but force https on all frontends

Here's my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(wp-admin)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

I think your redirect is fine. Look for a line like this in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

and set it to `false`.